# Function for writing structs to text file

Tags: function, text-files

I wrote this function for writing structs to text file but when I try to call it in my main function it just ends my program like it doesnt exist.

```
void unos_aritkala(void) {
    FILE* pok = NULL;
    pok = fopen("artikli.txt", "a+");
    if (pok == NULL) {
        printf("Datoteka se ne moze otvoriti\n");
    }
    else {
        ARTIKL artikl; 
        printf("Unesite ime artikla: ");
        scanf("%s", &artikl.ime);
        printf("Unesite cijenu artikla ");
        scanf("%f", &artikl.cijena);
        printf("UNesite ID artikla ");
        scanf("%d", &artikl.ID);
        fprintf(pok, "Ime: %c\n, Cijena: %f\n ID: %d\n", artikl.ime, artikl.cijena, artikl.ID);
    }
    fclose(pok);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf` is for formatted output and if I'm not wrong no matter how you `fopen()`ed the file it outputs only strings.

Use `fwrite()` instead.

[Detailed tutorialspoint.com link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm)

For your particular case you may just write

```
pok = fopen( "artikli.txt" , "w" );
fwrite(artikl, sizeof(ARTIKL), 1 , pok);
fclose(pok);
```

For multiple structs (for example in an array), once you opened the file you can repeatedly call `fwrite()` for each element.

```
// Assuming you have your structs in an array named list of size listSize
for(i=0; i< listSize; ++i)
 fwrite(list[i], sizeof(ARTIKL), 1, pok);
```

Comment: I fixed this but how to repeat that function multiple times? I tried using for loop but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you provide your use case ?

Comment: I am making program like cash register so I want to use that for adding items to database.

Comment: See updated answer for that. I am not sure about the database part though. Maybe you should look up some useful examples about the topic before you dive into the implementation.

Comment: I want user to determine how much items he wants to add to file so is there any way to run multiple times this function?

Comment: Of course, you just need the iterate your scanf(), printf() block above as long as the user wants. You can achieve that with a `do while` block where user asked if he wants to continue, (simple scanf before while would do) then you check this value inside the while parentheses.

    do{ }
    while(value)

Comment: I am getting error for fwrite() saying that there is no suitable conversion function from "ARTIKL" to "const void*"

Comment: try passing the address of your struct and you might need to update the function call to switch sizeof and, nmemb fields. 
`fwrite(&list[i], sizeof(ARTIKL),1, pok);`